# from spark dataframe to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe that I created it by this way :

```
tx_df = (spark
         .read
         .parquet("/data/file"))



tx_ecommerce = tx_df.filter(tx_df["POS_Cardholder_Presence"]=="ECommerce").show()
```

I try to convert tx_commerce to pandas dataframe. I tryed like this :

```
tx_ecommerce.toPandas()
```

But I got this error :

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 tx_ecommerce.toPandas()
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'toPandas'

Any help please to resolve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

when you put .show() at the end, it is not a pyspark data frame anymore.

Remove it and it should work.

```
tx_ecommerce =tx_df.filter(tx_df["POS_Cardholder_Presence"]=="ECommerce")

tx_ecommerce.toPandas()
```

Comment: no worries. could you please accept it as a correct answer too? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this to read a parquet file:

```
import pandas as pd
txt = pd.read_parquet("/data/file.parquet")
txt_ecommerce = txt.loc[txt.POS_Cardholder_Presence =="ECommerce"]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).